# Unconfirmed transaction for over five days

Tags: blockchain.info

I sent a transaction to someone that makes use of quidax wallet, from my blockchain, and for over five days it has not being confirmed, what could Happened and is it possible for me to get back my fund

Comment: What was the fee rate used for this transaction? Which wallet was used for it? Was it RBF enabled? Did the transaction have any change address from your wallet?

Comment: Fee=0.00004115 BTC
Fee per byte=5.049 sat/B
Fee per weight unit=1.262 Sat/WU And i got information like received at 09:21 yesterday and i don't know what it means and who received,? Although my confirmation is still 0 of 6

Comment: You have used low fee rate. It can take few hours/days for it to get confirmed as others are using higher fee rate and miners prioritize based on fee rate. You can check mempool and your tx in it here by entering transaction id: https://mempool.observer

Comment: fd998def26c5cd66990e973df62fc128d05a49ed2cab0c3d4a20a0b5ae7396ef

Comment: I saw something like : 20,000 5sat/vbyte But i don't know what it means please explain

Comment: Fee rate used in the transaction shared by you is **5 sat/vByte**  and there are approximately 20,000 transactions unconfirmed which are using less than 5 sat/vByte so your transaction is above them and below others that are using higher fee rate. Total unconfirmed transactions: ~51000

Comment: So i will only be verified when they must have finished with the 51,000 other confirmations,? And again what if new transaction is done on a higher rate after now will they still b ahead of me. And how do i know how many people that will be verified first before me

Comment: You can use "comments" instead of using "answers" for related questions. I would suggest you to join this chatroom, share your question link and someone would help you understand how things work when they are free: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8089/mempool

Comment: I am not familiar with this site.. please is their any media like Facebook or Whatsapp you can help chat me frk.